# Image links are not clickable when in absolute position in container div

Tags: html, css

I have a div container with a background image and two icons over the background image. The problem is when I point the mouse over the icons it doesn't allow to click on the image and open the hyperlink. Here is the code I've got:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .containerdiv { float: left; position: relative; left: -10px; top: -10px;}
    .cornerimage1 { position: absolute; top: 75%; left: 0.5%;}
    .cornerimage2 { position: absolute; bottom: 23%; left: 0.5%;}
</style>

<div class="containerdiv">
    <iframe src="images/mybackground.jpg" width="550" height="314" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <a href="//facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="alternate"><img class="cornerimage1" src="images/iconfacebook.png" alt="" width="90" height="34"></a>
    <a href="//twitter.com" target="_blank" rel="alternate"><img class="cornerimage2" src="images/icontwitter.png" alt="" width="90" height="34"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: </style>


<div class="containerdiv">
  

<iframe src="images/mybackground.jpg" width="550" height="314" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<a href="//facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="alternate"><img class="cornerimage1" src="images/iconfacebook.png" alt="" width="90" height="34"></a>

<a href="//twitter.com" target="_blank" rel="alternate"><img class="cornerimage2" src="images/icontwitter.png" alt="" width="90" height="34"></a>
 
</div>

Comment: 1. edit your post 2. https://jsfiddle.net/yknooydq/ thats a jsfiddle with your code and the imgs are clickable. so its another problem with your code. What you could try is set the `z-index` for `cornerimage1` and `cornerimage2` to `100` in css.

Comment: @hansTheFranz: I turned the code in the question into a code snippet, and the links fail for me just as the OP describes. They *do* work in the fiddle though, so something is different.